# SQL Server : constraints to ensure unique value on 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have a table with 2 columns, `Username` & `Email`

```
Username    |    Email
-------------------------
a@a.com     |     a@a.com
b@b.com     |     c@c.com
```

I want the `Username` to be unique in both columns except the current record.

Same for the `Email` column.

For example, if I am trying to insert the following rows into the table, it should not be allowed.

```
Username    |    Email
e@e.com     |     b@b.com
c@c.com     |     f@f.com
```

Can this be done via SQL Server constraints?

Best regards

Comment: Not quite clear what you want... **why** should the insert of these two new rows fail? I don't see any "duplication" here that you could check for

Comment: So, the rules are a) No username should match any existing username or email, b) No email should match any existing username or email, and c) There is an exception that, within a single row, the username and email may be equal? If so, no, you cannot implement this with constraints.

Comment: I did that via trigger instead now,  seems there is no way with only constraints